# Upload image to the server from android native camera via Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

Fiddle of my html page [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/70LLLrdg/3/)

Now using this i'm able to open the native camera in an android device.

But I can't save the image and then send this image to the server so that i can save it in my database.

What can I do after selecting the image from the device gallery to send and save the image on the server?

Opening native camera function used:

```
 function choosePhoto() {
        var file = Android.choosePhoto();
        window.alert("file = " + file);
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking on how to send a selected image to a database? And what type of database is it ?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the related question you asked,
check my answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41570241/3518278

My answer covers how to open the camera and fetch the image from the device and set it in the html.

How this helps in this scenario of yours is that you can use js/jQuery to fetch the image from the view < img> and do a ajax / http request to post/put it to the server. In your case you dont need a < img> to set the image you can save the data in a variable and directly post it to the server OR set the image in a hidden < img> and proceed.

So you will use below code to fetch and send the image to the html via JSInterface

```
                    // Get the image data in a byte array
                    File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
                    Bitmap bitmap = Util.convertImageFileToBitmap(imageFile.getAbsolutePath(), Constants.IMAGE_COMPRESSED_WIDTH, Constants.IMAGE_COMPRESSED_HEIGHT);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
                    byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();

                    // get the base 64 string of the image which was converted to a byte array above
                    final String imgBase64String = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:imageData('" + imgBase64String + "')");
                        }
                    });
```

Your html will contain the following snippet

```
function imageData(data){
    document.getElementById('displayImage').setAttribute( 'src', 'data:image/png;base64,'+data );        
  }
```

Sample project covering the functionality you are seeking can be found here

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BwRMp8dK9LMLeEo5cTlXVE9ZUW8?usp=sharing